# Changing the GridSpec properties after generating the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-gridspec

Suppose something comes up in my plot that mandates that I change the height ratio between two subplots that I've generated within my plot. I've tried changing `GridSpec`'s height ratio to no avail.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[2, 1])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = fig.axes[0]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2 = fig.axes[1]

ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 0])

gs.height_ratios = [2, 5]
```

The last line has no effect on the plot ratio.

In my actual code, it is not feasible without major reworking to set the height_ratios to 2:5 ahead of time.

How do I get this to update like I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axes` of relevant subplots can be manipulated and adjusted to get new height ratios.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[2, 1]) #nrows, ncols

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax1 = fig.axes[0]
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax2 = fig.axes[1]

ax1.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
ax2.plot([0, 1], [1, 0])

# new height ratio: 2:5 is required for the 2 subplots
rw, rh = 2, 5

# get dimensions of the 2 axes
box1 = ax1.get_position()
box2 = ax2.get_position()
# current dimensions
w1,h1 = box1.x1-box1.x0, box1.y1-box1.y0
w2,h2 = box2.x1-box2.x0, box2.y1-box2.y0
top1 = box1.y0+h1
#top2 = box2.y0+h2
full_h = h1+h2   #total height

# compute new heights for each axes
new_h1 = full_h*rw/(rw + rh)
new_h2 = full_h*rh/(rw + rh)

#btm1,btm2 = box1.y0, box2.y0
new_bottom1 = top1-new_h1

# finally, set new location/dimensions of the axes
ax1.set_position([box1.x0, new_bottom1, w1, new_h1])
ax2.set_position([box2.x0, box2.y0, w2, new_h2])

plt.show()
```

The output for ratio: (2, 5):

[image: 2x5]

The output for (2, 10):

[image: 2x10]